# Can Tufte sidenotes work in the multicols environment?

Tags: multicol, tufte

I am writing handouts using the `tufte-handout` document class. I use the `multicol` package to make  a two-column list of vocabulary terms. One term needs an explanation, which I would like to reference using the `\sidenote` command. Unfortunately, this does not work in the `multicol` environment. Can `\sidenote` be modified to work inside the `multicols` environment?

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{multicol} % multiple column layout facilities
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
Vocabulary One \sidenote{A note about Vocabulary One.} \\
Vocabulary Two \\
Vocab Three \\
Vocab Four
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```